# What happens in Windows when out of memory (RAM) and paging is disabled?

Tags: windows-xp, memory

Should any error message appear or would applications crash?

I've seen the following message:

> ...exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.

This tends to happen when the system has been under a bigger load. I haven't been able to monitor any exact memory usage yet.

This is on Windows XP SP3, build 2600.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Windows crashes if it runs out of memory.

Comment: What happens? It depends. Some times the crash can be caught and dealt with gracefully and some times it crashes. However nothing you said in your post states it's a memory issue. Open task manager and see how much resource it is using. Look in event viewer to see detail

Answer (score 0):

In order to install windows and/or boot into windows, a certain amount of memory is already necessary. Windows will not install if there is insufficient memory. But if you have enough memory, install windows, then remove memory, windows will not boot.

That said, lets say you have enough memory to run windows, but you start a program that requires more memory than windows has?

Well, what happens depends on a few things.

Did the programmer used windows API calls to manage memory correctly, if so, the program should simply display an error message when trying to execute certain tasks. If loading the program itself exceeds memory, it is likely to crash at startup giving a "This program terminated unexpectedly. Send error report to microsoft"

However, if the programmer did not use microsoft API calls, then it determines how well the programmer anticipated possible memory issues and tested the program finding memory problems. If the programmer did not add checks for any memory problems, the program will crash, or depending on what the programmer did it could even crash windows itself.

Programming languages such as c++ allow direct memory management and is powerful enough to crash windows when code was inserted without proper checks.

Windows does have certain protection build-in, in the form of BSoD's, but that is still a crash.

Comment: This answer is correct.  A program written in a managed language like C# or Java would generate an exception if the exception was caught.  A program written I a language like C++ can throw an exception but it can also just crash.  Even if the C# program exception wasn't itself caught an exception would still be thrown it just would result in an unrecoverable state

Comment: Thanks for a great answer lpchip. So regarding the error message..are you saying that the "xx.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. we are sorry for the inconvenience." are most likely to not have anything to do with memory issues ?

Comment: I was not saying that, but it is true. It can be a cause, but it doesn't have to be. The prorammer could easily overflow an integer or otherwise create a memory feedback loop and become unresponsive. Its even possible to execute a specific line of code that will crash the program (debug instruction).

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot disable paging on Windows. I presume you mean there is no paging file. And the answer is -- nothing unusual happens. This is a perfectly normal condition.

When Windows is out of RAM and needs RAM for something, it does one of the following things:

1. Clean pages that are just copies of information that can be retrieved from disk again if needed are discarded. This makes more free pages.
2. Dirty pages that contain modified copies of files are written back to disk, thus making the pages clean, allowing them to be discarded as well.

Typically the system would have a third option -- dirty pages that don't contain modified copies of files could be written to the paging file, allowing them to be discarded too, but that option's not available if you don't have a paging file. That tends to result in severely reduced performance as the system memory gets cluttered with dirty pages that are never accessed.

Like most modern operating systems, Windows is typically out of RAM almost all the time. If it were not out of RAM, it would have a disk cache that was smaller than it could have, resulting in needless I/O operations.

Comment: I assume the swapfile is meant here, something you can disable.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer David. So you mean..even if you check the "No paging file" under virtual memory options..windows are still using paging somehow ?

Comment: If that were the case, windows would not present you with a serious warning the moment you try to disable it.

Comment: @Nicco Yes. Windows pages no matter what you do. For example, no matter what you do, when you run a program, Windows will *not* load the entire program into memory. It will load the beginning of the program into memory and allow the rest of the program to be paged in as needed. That way, if the program does very little (say, just waits for a command or connection), you won't waste lots of RAM holding the entire application.

Comment: @LPChip Disabling the paging file means that Windows cannot get dirty, unbacked pages out of memory no matter what. This seriously compromises Windows' ability to make effective use of memory. Typically what happens is that the set of clean pages gets squeezed, and you get unnecessary I/O as clean pages load and unload while RAM is filled with dirty pages that may never get accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Out of memory warnings and errors mean the commit charge is reaching the commit limit. This has nothing to do with a shortage of available RAM. The errors can occur even when there is plenty of RAM available.

The commit limit is RAM size + pagefile size - a small overhead. With no pagefile it will be slightly less than RAM size. With many common workloads, even with 4 GB RAM, that may not be enough.

The best solution is to enable the pagefile, preferably set to system managed.